# Linux boots to recovery mode, mounting /home and loging out brings up lightdm

Tags: mount, login

I am having an odd problem when i boot.
It brings me to the recovery mode and tells me to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> or enter my root password.
When I enter the root password, I mount my `/dev/mapper/sdc1_crypt` which is my `/home` drive. if I log out of the root shell it then launches `lightdm` and I can sign into my user account as if nothing happened.

How can I fix it so i dont have to do this each time I boot?

I'm using Debian.

Comment: The messages shows onscreen at boot time should give an indication as to _why_ it's booting into single-user mode.   Correct that issue, and it will no longer happen.  Most common cause is a dirty filesystem.  Boot to single-user, and `fsck` the indicated partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using `fsck` on the diskdrive in question